# Powershell Function for getting number of minutes since file last written to

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to convert the following powershell code into a function.

Id like to be able to specify a path ($filePath) and receive the number of minutes since it was last written to. The below works perfectly well, but id like it as a function as it needs to be repeated multiple times.

```
  $file = get-item $filePath
  $date = Get-Date
  $fileDate = $file.LastWriteTime
  $duration = ($date - $fileDate)
  $mins = $duration.TotalMinutes
  $RoundedMinsSinceLastWritten = [math]::Round($mins,2)
```

When i call $RoundedMinsSinceLastWritten, I get the value that I need (the number of minutes to 2 decimal places). I don't know what to call when this is in a function.

The goal is to have the value inside a variable.

Comment: what prevents you from adding `function func() {}` around the snippet and make some small necessary changes? Did you do any research? Did you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.1?

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have explained more. When i create this as a function, i don't know how to get my value back out. If its not a function, i can call $RoundedMinsSinceLastWritten. i.e >  write-host $RoundedMinsSinceLastWritten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning a group of statements into a function is as easy as enclosing them in `{}` and prefix it with the `function` keyword and a function name:

```
function Get-FileAge {
  # code goes here...
}
```

> Id like to be able to specify a path ($filePath)

So we'll need to declare a `$FilePath` parameter:

```
function Get-FileAge {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$FilePath
  )

  $file = Get-Item $filePath
  $date = Get-Date
  $fileDate = $file.LastWriteTime
  $duration = ($date - $fileDate)
  $mins = $duration.TotalMinutes
  return [math]::Round($mins,2)
}
```

See the [`about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters` help file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.1) for more details on parameter declarations in PowerShell functions.

Comment: Perfect. Its the "return" i was after in the last line. Thank you Mathias